# Bit Reversal - not clear what the output is

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

I am reading the following example :

```
  Var1(REG1, 0U, 16U);
  Var2(REG2, 0U, 8U);

   UINT32 FirstReg = Getaddress1(Var1); //the dimension is 16 bit

   FirstReg = ((FirstReg >> 1) & 0x5555) | ((FirstReg << 1) & 0xaaaa);
   FirstReg = ((FirstReg >> 2) & 0x3333) | ((FirstReg << 2) & 0xcccc);
   FirstReg = ((FirstReg >> 4) & 0x0f0f) | ((FirstReg << 4) & 0xf0f0);
   FirstReg = ((FirstReg >> 8) & 0x00ff) | ((FirstReg << 8) & 0xff00);
   FirstReg = (FirstReg << 8);

   UINT32 SecondReg = Getaddress2(Var2);//the dimension is 8 bit
   SecondReg = ((SecondReg >> 1) & 0x5555) | ((SecondReg << 1) & 0xaaaa);
   SecondReg = ((SecondReg >> 2) & 0x3333) | ((SecondReg << 2) & 0xcccc);
   SecondReg = ((SecondReg >> 4) & 0x0f0f) | ((SecondReg << 4) & 0xf0f0);
   SecondReg = ((SecondReg >> 8) & 0x00ff) | ((SecondReg << 8) & 0xff00);
   SecondReg = (SecondReg >> 8);

   return (FirstReg | SecondReg);
```

Basically as far as i undestand the intention is to reverse the bits read in the 2 UINT32 Reg(s) variables and collect in only 1 variable of UINT32 type.

I don't get if the first bit (for example) of SecondReg will become the 17th bit of the returned variable or the first one.

Comment: For reference: https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#ReverseParallel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, even if the algorythm works with 32 bits integers, only the 16 least significant bits are used because they are *anded* with 16 bits only values.

So after the first part (before the last shift) `FirstReg` and `SecondReg` contains the 16 least significant bits of the original values reversed.

Then `FirstReg` is shifted left 8 bits and `SecondReg` is shifted right 8 bits and both are *ored*. The result is a 32 bits values composed with (most significant byte to least): O, high order byte of `FirstReg`, low order byte of `FirstReg`, high order byte of `SecondReg`

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, so basically the following comment which i found reading the code above is clearly wrong: "Read the bit  #1 of FirstReg and put value into bit #1 of returned value,
 read the bit  #2 of FirstReg and put value into bit #2   of returned value".... "Read the bit  #1 of SecondReg and put value into bit #16   of returned value"